# How to add all the numbers of a specific column in UNIX without using awk command?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed

Let us take a sample file with the contents below, an expense report containing items and their prices:

```
$ cat file
Item1,200
Item2,500
Item345,900
Item20896,800
Item111,600
```

Now, a friend challenged me to get the *total price* of all items -- but *without* using `awk`.  Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by `awk command doesn't work on my system`?

Comment: Of course `awk` works on your system (if it doesn't, you're using a system that isn't on topic here). Should we assume you are referring to a specific `awk` script that you tried which failed? What script?

Comment: Yes. but the thing is that my friend told me that you can't get this without using awk and i want to challenge him.

Comment: "can't be done without awk" is pure nonsense, as you could write a program to do this in *any* language and install it in /usr/bin. Are you looking for a solution in posix sh, csh, bash, zsh, ksh?

Comment: If this is more of a coding challenge than an actual problem, it should probably be moved to [programming puzzles](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5):

With GNU bash:

```
while IFS="," read -r item number; do ((sum=$sum+$number)); done < file; echo $sum
```

Output:

```
3000
```

Answer (score 4):

I really don't see why you don't want to use `awk` but sure, here are some alternatives:

- Perl ([TIMTOWDY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it))

  ```
  $ perl -F, -lane '$k+=$F[1];}{print $k' file 
  3000
  $ perl -lne '/,(\d+)/;$k+=$1;}{print $k' file 
  3000
  $ perl -F, -lane '$k+=$F[1];END{print $k}' file 
  3000
  ```
- classic *nix tools

  ```
  $ cut -d, -f2 file | tr '\n' '+' | sed 's/+$/\n/' | bc
  3000
  $ cut -d, -f2 file | paste -d'+' - - - - - | bc
  3000
  ```
- Modern bourne family shells (e.g. bash, ksh, zsh)

  ```
  $ k=0; while IFS=, read a num; do ((k+=num)); done < file ; echo "$k"; 
  3000
  ```
- POSIX shells

  ```
  k=0; while IFS=, read a num; do k=$((k+num)); done < file ; echo "$k";
  ```

Comment: "Pure shell" must mean _bash_, since the code between `do` and `done` can't run in POSIX shell _dash_.

Comment: @agc well no, it means most modern shells of the sh family including bash, zsh, ksh and probably others. There are more than two shells in the world. But, fair enough, I added a POSIX approach.

Comment: That `paste -d'+' - - - - -` depends on the programmer manually counting 5 lines of OP's input data.  It won't work correctly if there's 1000 lines.

Comment: @agc well, yes. The OP asked for a solution to this specific problem and this one has 5 lines. The other solutions don't have this limitation.

Comment: Certainly your *other* six solutions are correct.  This sole exception is because the OP asked a general question of "how to add all the numbers of a specific column", (not just _five_ numbers), and refers to that instance given as a "sample file".   Expecting the OP to list *all possible* sample file lengths seems impractical.

Answer (score 4):

Using [num-utils](http://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/):

```
numsum -s, -2 file
```

Using [datamash](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/):

```
datamash  -t, sum 2 < file
```

Using [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq):

```
cut -d, -f2 file | jq -s add
```

Comment: +1, those are nifty tools. Are you sure about the `numsum` one? That gives an error on my Arch (`Use of uninitialized value $final_output[0] in join or string at /sbin/numsum line 112.`) but it looks like a bug in the Arch package.

Comment: I'm using Lubuntu _num-utils_ package, v0.5-11, which runs under _perl_ v5.20.2-6ubuntu0.2.